# Running a cron every 30 seconds

Tags: ubuntu, cron, scheduled-tasks

Ok so I have a cron that I need to run every 30 seconds.

Here is what I have:

```
*/30 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /srv/last_song/releases/20120308133159 && script/rails runner -e production '\''Song.insert_latest'\'''
```

It runs, but is this running every 30 minutes or 30 seconds?

Also, I have been reading that cron might not be the best tool to use if I run it that often. Is there another better tool that I can use or install on Ubuntu 11.04 that will be a better option? Is there a way to fix the above cron?

Comment: CommaToast, and what happens if your Javascript or Java app falls over for some reason and exits? How will it restart? :-)

Comment: Add a little NodeJS app, lol. Why not a little c++ app? While we're at it, we can name  it 'cron' and run it as a service.

Comment: I just found this while looking at user profiles and saw you were online less than 1h ago (just to check if the acc is still in use), is there any specific reason that you didn't accept any of the answers below?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/301946/133195

Answer (score 905, accepted):

You have `*/30` in the *minutes* specifier - that means every minute but with a step of 30 (in other words, every half hour). Since `cron` does not go down to sub-minute resolutions, you will need to find another way.

One possibility, though it's a bit of a kludge<sup>(a)</sup>, is to have two jobs, one offset by 30 seconds:

```
# Need these to run on 30-sec boundaries, keep commands in sync.
* * * * *              /path/to/executable param1 param2
* * * * * ( sleep 30 ; /path/to/executable param1 param2 )
```

You'll see I've added comments and formatted to ensure it's easy to keep them synchronised.

Both `cron` jobs actually run every minute but the *latter* one will wait half a minute before executing the "meat" of the job, `/path/to/executable`.

For other (non-`cron`-based) options, see the other answers here, particularly the ones mentioning `fcron` and `systemd`. These are probably preferable assuming your system has the ability to use them (such as installing `fcron` or having a distro with `systemd` in it).

---

If you *don't* want to use the kludgy solution, you can use a loop-based solution with a small modification. You'll still have to manage keeping your process running in some form but, once that's sorted, the following script should work:

```
#!/bin/env bash

# Debug code to start on minute boundary and to
# gradually increase maximum payload duration to
# see what happens when the payload exceeds 30 seconds.

((maxtime = 20))
while [[ "$(date +%S)" != "00" ]]; do true; done

while true; do
    # Start a background timer BEFORE the payload runs.

    sleep 30 &

    # Execute the payload, some random duration up to the limit.
    # Extra blank line if excess payload.

    ((delay = RANDOM % maxtime + 1))
    ((maxtime += 1))
    echo "$(date) Sleeping for ${delay} seconds (max ${maxtime})."
    [[ ${delay} -gt 30 ]] && echo
    sleep ${delay}

    # Wait for timer to finish before next cycle.

    wait
done
```

The trick is to use a `sleep 30` but to start it in the *background* before your payload runs. Then, after the payload is finished, just wait for the background `sleep` to finish.

If the payload takes `n` seconds (where `n <= 30`), the wait after the payload will then be `30 - n` seconds. If it takes *more* than 30 seconds, then the next cycle will be delayed until the payload is finished, but no longer.

You'll see that I have debug code in there to start on a one-minute boundary to make the output initially easier to follow. I also gradually increase the maximum payload time so you'll eventually see the payload exceed the 30-second cycle time (an extra blank line is output so the effect is obvious).

A sample run follows (where cycles normally start 30 seconds after the previous cycle):

```
Tue May 26 20:56:00 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 9 seconds (max 21).
Tue May 26 20:56:30 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 19 seconds (max 22).
Tue May 26 20:57:00 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 9 seconds (max 23).
Tue May 26 20:57:30 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 7 seconds (max 24).
Tue May 26 20:58:00 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 2 seconds (max 25).
Tue May 26 20:58:30 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 8 seconds (max 26).
Tue May 26 20:59:00 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 20 seconds (max 27).
Tue May 26 20:59:30 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 25 seconds (max 28).
Tue May 26 21:00:00 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 5 seconds (max 29).
Tue May 26 21:00:30 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 6 seconds (max 30).
Tue May 26 21:01:00 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 27 seconds (max 31).
Tue May 26 21:01:30 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 25 seconds (max 32).
Tue May 26 21:02:00 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 15 seconds (max 33).
Tue May 26 21:02:30 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 10 seconds (max 34).
Tue May 26 21:03:00 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 5 seconds (max 35).
Tue May 26 21:03:30 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 35 seconds (max 36).

Tue May 26 21:04:05 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 2 seconds (max 37).
Tue May 26 21:04:35 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 20 seconds (max 38).
Tue May 26 21:05:05 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 22 seconds (max 39).
Tue May 26 21:05:35 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 18 seconds (max 40).
Tue May 26 21:06:05 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 33 seconds (max 41).

Tue May 26 21:06:38 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 31 seconds (max 42).

Tue May 26 21:07:09 AWST 2020 Sleeping for 6 seconds (max 43).
```

If you want to avoid the kludgy solution, this is probably better. You'll still need a `cron` job (or equivalent) to periodically detect if this script is running and, if not, start it. But the script itself then handles the timing.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Some of my workmates would say that kludges are my specialty :-)

Comment: This is a great workaround, so much so i think it transcends its kludginess

Comment: wouldn't this work too? `* * * * * ( /path/to/executable param1 param2; sleep 30 ; /path/to/executable param1 param2 )`

Comment: @rubo77, only if it took less than a second to run :-) If it took 29 seconds, it would happen at 0:00:00, 0:00.59, 0:01:00, 0:01:59 and so on.

Comment: What are the round brackets for around the second line?

Comment: This is a lovely solution to an issue that otherwise cripples crons effectiveness for certain tasks that require execution in fractions of minutes. Thank you.

Comment: This solution is indeed evil. Its unneeded duplication and a kludge. Sujoshi's bash loop is better; Adi Chiru's fcron suggestion is better; but if you have any modern Linux OS, the SystemD timer solution below is best.

Comment: @Guss, I freely admitted it was a kludge but the duplication is local so can be seen (and kept in sync) easily. If you want to ensure you're not having to continuously change both, just make a shell script that gets changed and run it. For a bash-loop-sleep solution, it's not the same thing - a command taking 20s to run will execute every 50 seconds, not 30. On the plus side, `fcron` looks promising (assuming you're allowed to install new stuff) - will have a look into that. No need for me to look into system, we already use it heavily in our embedded system and we're reasonably happy with it.

Comment: @Guss, in addition, I've added a comment referencing the `fcron` and `systemd` answers (no point duplicating the info in this answer). If available, `systemd` is preferable even with the minimal extra setup required.

Comment: @JustAMartin, cronmaker doesn't appear to go below minute resolution, and quartz (I believe) *can* actually handle resolutions down to the second.

Comment: @paxdiablo cronmaker generates final result with seconds. But ok, it also mentions `CronMaker uses Quartz`. This is so confusing - newcomers to GNU/Linux have no idea which cron is Quartz and which isn't, and if their chosen distro is using Quartz or isn't. Why Quartz is called `cron` at all, and not `quartz` - it would avoid the confusion.

Comment: @JustAMartin: sorry, didn't notice that, I just assumed that, because it only allowed you to generate to a minutes resolution, it was standard cron. I agree with your comments about naming but I'm not aware of any distro that uses quartz by default (maybe Oracle Linux because they want to push Java).

Comment: A shame crontab didn't add an extra seconds digit

Comment: It's debatable which one of these is more kludgy; the fact that it took so many more words to explain what option #2 was even doing seems to suggest that it's the more kludgy of the two solutions. If I can look at a solution and instantly know what it's doing, that makes it less-clumsy and kludgy.

Comment: @NigelAlderton The parentheses cause the commands to run in a subshell. There is no need for that here, so they are basically redundant and (slightly) wasteful.

Answer (score 125):

If you are running a recent Linux OS with SystemD, you can use the SystemD Timer unit to run your script at any granularity level you wish (theoretically down to nanoseconds), and - if you wish - much more flexible launching rules than Cron ever allowed. **No `sleep` kludges required**

It takes a bit more to set up than a single line in a cron file, but if you need anything better than "Every minute", it is well worth the effort.

The SystemD timer model is basically this: *timers are units that start service units when a timer elapses*.

So for every script/command that you want to schedule, you must have a service unit and then an additional timer unit. A single timer unit can include multiple schedules, so you normally wouldn't need more than one timer and one service.

Here is a simple example that logs "Hello World" every 10 seconds:

(to create these files, you can use `sudo tee path-to-file` and paste the file content then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, or use your text editor of choice)

`/etc/systemd/system/helloworld.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Say Hello
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/logger -i Hello World
```

`/etc/systemd/system/helloworld.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Say Hello every 10 seconds
[Timer]
OnBootSec=10
OnUnitActiveSec=10
AccuracySec=1ms
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

After setting up these units (in `/etc/systemd/system`, as described above, for a system-wide setting, or at `~/.config/systemd/user` for a user-specific setup), you need to enable the timer (not the service though) by running `systemctl enable --now helloworld.timer` (the `--now` flag also starts the timer immediately, otherwise, it will only start after the next boot, or user login).

The `[Timer]` section fields used here are as follows:

- `OnBootSec` - start the service this many seconds after each boot.
- `OnUnitActiveSec` - start the service this many seconds after the last time the service was started. This is what causes the timer to repeat itself and behave like a cron job.
- `AccuracySec` - sets the accuracy of the timer. Timers are only as accurate as this field sets, and the default is 1 minute (emulates cron). The main reason to not demand the best accuracy is to improve power consumption - if SystemD can schedule the next run to coincide with other events, it needs to wake the CPU less often. The `1ms` in the example above is not ideal - I usually set accuracy to `1` (1 second) in my sub-minute scheduled jobs, but that would mean that if you look at the log showing the "Hello World" messages, you'd see that it is often late by 1 second. If you're OK with that, I suggest setting the accuracy to 1 second or more.

As you may have noticed, this timer doesn't mimic Cron all that well - in the sense that the command doesn't start at the beginning of every wall clock period (i.e. it doesn't start on the 10th second on the clock, then the 20th and so on). Instead is just happens when the timer ellapses. If the system booted at 12:05:37, then the next time the command runs will be at 12:05:47, then at 12:05:57, etc. If you are interested in actual wall clock accuracy, then you may want to replace the `OnBootSec` and `OnUnitActiveSec` fields and instead set an `OnCalendar` rule with the schedule that you want (which as far as I understand can't be faster than 1 second, using the calendar format). The above example can also be written as:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:*:00,10,20,30,40,50
```

Last note: as you probably guessed, the `helloworld.timer` unit starts the `helloworld.service` unit because they have the same name (minus the unit type suffix). This is the default, but you can override that by setting the `Unit` field for the `[Timer]` section.

More gory details can be found at:

- [Arch Linux Wiki page about SystemD timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers) which gives a very good overview of the topic, with examples.
- [`man systemd.timer`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html)
- [`man systemd.time`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html)
- [`man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)
- [`man systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)

Comment: I often come across better answers like this under the comments section. IMHO, though cron has been staple for scheduled jobs, this answer should be the accepted one since its not a "hack job" of sleeps and risking parallelization of executing long-running tasks considering the interval/frequency needed

Comment: I wonder if it's possible on Alpine because people say it's OpenRC there, not systemd.

Comment: @Nakilon: Alpine was originally meant as a minimalistic OS for containers and as such it doesn't need a complex system runtime such as SystemD. IMO OpenRC is also totally an overkill for a container - if you have a good reason for multi-process containers, use supervisord or something as simple, and I also question your need for running cron in such situations. I'm aware that some people run Alpine in non-container situations, and I wish they'd stop - Alpine hasn't passed even the very basic hardening and QA required for running as a main OS.

Comment: @Guss, the goal isn't about multi-process but about running the task more frequently than once in a minute. I need it to run once in 10 seconds. I'm currently using cron calling  the .sh script with six commands chained like this `{ ruby main.rb & sleep 10 ;} && ... && ruby main.rb`. You see, in the last iteration I don't call `sleep` -- I thought that I need to inline the loop like this because I had the `"process is still running"` error. The error message is gone but it still skips the second iteration I don't why. Still debugging.

Comment: Lets continue this discussion in a chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223813 ?

Comment: Systemd is not available in every os. This is a good addition, but not a proper *solution* for the question.

Comment: Can I use this as a regular user, without superuser privileges?

Comment: @gerrit - yes, it is covered in the answer above as the "user-specific" configuration.

Answer (score 82):

You can't. Cron has a 60 sec granularity.

```
* * * * * cd /srv/last_song/releases/20120308133159 && script/rails runner -e production '\''Song.insert_latest'\''
* * * * * sleep 30 && cd /srv/last_song/releases/20120308133159 && script/rails runner -e production '\''Song.insert_latest'\''
```

Comment: Is this syntax equivalent to paxdiablo's? Or are there subtle differences?

Comment: The difference is: I used the original path to the binary. @paxdiablo used a kind of meta-syntax. (and invokes a sub-shell)

Comment: I meant, using `&&` instead of `( ; )`.

Comment: Sorry. No, there is a difference; the `&&` operator short-circuits, so the next command in the chain is not executed if the previous one failed.

Comment: This granularity should not be an issue for a sub-minute resolution.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Both of these are slightly dubious; the `&&` _in theory_ could cause the script to not run if for some reason `sleep` would fail. But it's hard to imagine a scenario in which `sleep` would fail and the script would work. Also, whether that's good or bad depends on your requirements. Perhaps it's really better to not try if you can't even `sleep`.

Answer (score 41):

Cron's granularity is in minutes and *was not* designed to wake up every `x` seconds to run something. Run your repeating task within a loop and it should do what you need:

```
#!/bin/env bash
while [ true ]; do
 sleep 30
 # do what you need to here
done
```

Comment: Keep in mind that isn't _quite_ the same. If the job takes 25 seconds (for example), it will start every 55 seconds rather than every 30 seconds. It may not matter but you should be aware of the possible consequences.

Comment: You could run the job in background, then it will run in almost exactly 30 seconds.

Comment: while [true]do
 sleep 30
 # do what you need to here
done 

---------
done should be in small case

Comment: Won't  the `while [ true ]` cause you to have lots of instances of the same script, since cron will start a new one every minute?

Comment: You can do `sleep $remainingTime` where remainingTime is 30 minus the time the job took (and cap it at zero if it took > 30 seconds). So you take the time before and after the actual work, and calculate the difference.

Comment: @ChrisKoston The danger is that the job takes longer than 30 seconds if you run it in the background, so it could spin up dozens of jobs until the server runs out of memory.

Comment: Absolutely, the assumption is that the script, on average takes less then 30 seconds to execute. For the protection you can check how many processes you have running right before executing the script and set the threshold. num=\`pidof your_process | wc -w\`

Comment: If you divide the seconds by more than 60, you get a decimal. ie. */30 = 2, but */120=.5. Has anyone tried this? Does it work, or just not even run the cron job or?

Comment: Just for future info, you can use the `:` or `true` builtins (eg: `while true`) in `bash` (or `dash` or `zsh` for that matter), no need for the `[ ]` characters.

Comment: Indeed, `while [ true ]` _happens_ to work, but problably not for the reasons you imagine. In fact, `while [ false ]` would also work identically; you are checking whether the string inside `[ ... ]` is non-empty.

Answer (score 32):

No need for two cron entries, you can put it into one with:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c "/path/to/executable; sleep 30 ; /path/to/executable"
```

so in your case:

`* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c "cd /srv/last_song/releases/20120308133159 && script/rails runner -e production '\''Song.insert_latest'\'' ; sleep 30 ; cd /srv/last_song/releases/20120308133159 && script/rails runner -e production '\''Song.insert_latest'\''"`

Comment: Note: this only runs correct if the script takes less than a second to run

Comment: Rubo - if the job is taking seconds long (instead of milli or microseconds) to complete, then you wouldn't run it every thirty seconds to be able to run twice per minute.  So yes, start with 30 then subtract from that the approximate number of seconds per run, if greater than 1 second.

Comment: This also does not help if you want to receive error reports for each run separately.

Comment: joelin - the command I give does not prevent getting log or output data, I simplified the command to address the question.  To capture logging, each command can/should have output redirected if you need logging, e.g  script/rails runner -e production '\''Song.insert_latest'\'' could be written as script/rails runner -e production '\''Song.insert_latest'\'' 2>&1 > /path_to_logfile and again can be done for each command within the single cron entry.

Comment: Close enough, although for completeness you'd want to track the run time of the first execution and only sleep the remaining seconds to the 30 second marker

Answer (score 16):

Cron job cannot be used to schedule a job in seconds interval. i.e You cannot schedule a cron job to run every 5 seconds. The alternative is to write a shell script that uses `sleep 5` command in it.

Create a shell script every-5-seconds.sh using bash while loop as shown below.

```
$ cat every-5-seconds.sh
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 /home/ramesh/backup.sh
 sleep 5
done
```

Now, execute this shell script in the background using `nohup` as shown below. This will keep executing the script even after you logout from your session. This will execute your backup.sh shell script every 5 seconds.

```
$ nohup ./every-5-seconds.sh &
```

Comment: The time will drift. For example, if `backup.sh` takes 1.5 seconds to run, it will execute every 6.5 seconds. There are ways to avoid that, for example `sleep $((5 - $(date +%s) % 5))`

Comment: I am new to nohup, while executing your example, nohup is returning 'no such file or directory'. After some searches, you seems to missed out 'sh' after nohup. Like this: $ nohup sh ./every-5-seconds.sh &

Comment: It's more than just time drifting, it's double and tripple execution as crontab will start a new script while the other one is still running

Answer (score 14):

You can check out my answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17132983/1882929)

Basically, I've included there a bash script named "runEvery.sh" which you can run with cron every 1 minute and pass as arguments the real command you wish to run and the frequency in seconds in which you want to run it.

something like this

`* * * * * ~/bin/runEvery.sh 5 myScript.sh`

Answer (score 14):

Use watch:

```
$ watch --interval .30 script_to_run_every_30_sec.sh
```

Comment: can i use something like `$ watch --interval .10 php some_file.php`?  or `watch` works only with .sh files ?

Comment: You can run anything with watch. However the interval is between the end and start of the next command, so `--interval .30` will not run twice a minute.
I.e `watch -n 2 "sleep 1 && date +%s"` it will increment every 3s.

Comment: please note that `watch` was designed for terminal use, so - while it can work without a terminal (run with `nohup` then logout) or with a fake terminal (such as `screen`) - it has no affordances for cron-like behavior, such as recovering from failure, restarting after boot, etc'.

Answer (score 14):

Currently i'm using the below method. Works with no issues.

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -c ' for i in {1..X}; do YOUR_COMMANDS ; sleep Y ; done '
```

If you want to run every **N** seconds then **X** will be **60/N** and **Y** will be **N**.

Comment: You probably want to change `YOUR_COMMANDS` to `YOUR_COMMANDS &`, so that the command is launched to the background, otherwise, if the command takes more than a fraction of a second - it will delay the next launch. So with X=2 and Y=30, if the command takes 10 seconds - it will launch on the minute and then 40 seconds later, instead of 30. Kudus to @paxdiablo.

Comment: For some reason, if I omit the `/bin/bash -c` part (including the argument quotes) the script only runs every minute, ignoring the iteration (in my case `X=12` and `Y=5`).

Comment: I get `process already running`. Probably because the `sleep` needs some miliseconds more to die. It would be nice to not call the last `sleep`, i.e. for example call them only 5 times for 1 minute with 10 sec pauses.

Answer (score 9):

Use fcron (http://fcron.free.fr/) - gives you granularity in seconds and way better and more feature rich than cron (vixie-cron) and stable too. I used to make stupid things like having about 60 php scripts running on one machine in very stupid settings and it still did its job!

Comment: Confessions of a PHP developer ; )

Comment: Actually, confessions of a system engineer enabling PHP developers.... :)

Answer (score 8):

in dir `/etc/cron.d/`

new create a file `excute_per_30s`

```
* * * * * yourusername  /bin/date >> /home/yourusername/temp/date.txt
* * * * * yourusername sleep 30; /bin/date >> /home/yourusername/temp/date.txt
```

will run cron every 30 seconds

Answer (score 5):

The Linux Cron time-based scheduler by default does not execute jobs with shorter intervals than 1 minute. This config will show you a simple trick how to use Cron time-based scheduler to execute jobs using seconds interval. Let’s start with basics. The following cron job will be executed every minute:

```
* * * * * date >> /tmp/cron_test
```

The above job will be executed every minute and insert a current time into a file /tmp/cron_test. Now, that is easy! But what if we want to execute the same job every 30 seconds? To do that, we use cron to schedule two exactly same jobs but we postpone the execution of the second jobs using sleep command for 30 seconds. For example:

```
* * * * * date >> /tmp/cron_test
* * * * * sleep 30; date >> /tmp/cron_test
```

Answer (score 3):

Crontab job can be used to schedule a job in minutes/hours/days, but not in seconds. The alternative :

Create a script to execute every 30 seconds:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 30sec.sh

for COUNT in `seq 29` ; do
  cp /application/tmp/* /home/test
  sleep 30
done
```

Use `crontab -e` and a crontab to execute this script:

```
* * * * * /home/test/30sec.sh > /dev/null
```

Comment: if I understand this correctly, this script runs 30 times and waits 30 seconds in between every iteration. How does it make sense to run it every minute in cron?

Answer (score 3):

write one shell script
create .sh file

**nano every30second.sh**

and write script

```
#!/bin/bash
For  (( i=1; i <= 2; i++ ))
do
    write Command here
    sleep 30
done
```

then set cron for this script
**crontab -e**

`(* * * * *  /home/username/every30second.sh)`

this cron call .sh file in every 1 min & in the .sh file command is run 2 times in 1 min

if you want run script for 5 seconds then replace 30 by 5 and change for loop like this: `For  (( i=1; i <= 12; i++ ))`

when you select for any second then calculate 60/your second and write in For loop

Answer (score 3):

You can run that script as a service, restart every 30 seconds

Register a service

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/YOUR_SERVICE_NAME.service
```

Paste in the command below

```
Description=GIVE_YOUR_SERVICE_A_DESCRIPTION

Wants=network.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=YOUR_COMMAND_HERE
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload services

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Enable the service

```
sudo systemctl enable YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
```

Start the service

```
sudo systemctl start YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
```

Check the status of your service

```
systemctl status YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
```

Comment: It's going to work but it will create a LOT of log output into daemon.log or similar
Probably better to loop in the bash script in most cases

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [frequent-cron](https://github.com/homer6/frequent-cron) - it's old but very stable and you can step down to micro-seconds. At this point in time, the only thing that I would say against it is that I'm still trying to work out how to install it outside of init.d but as a native systemd service, but certainly up to Ubuntu 18 it's running just fine still using init.d (distance may vary on latter versions). It has the added advantage (?) of ensuring that it won't spawn another instance of the PHP script unless a prior one has completed, which reduces potential memory leakage issues.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the good answers. To make it simple I liked the mixed solution, with the control on crontab and the time division on the script. So this is what I did to run a script every 20 seconds (three times per minute). Crontab line:

```
 * * * * 1-6 ./a/b/checkAgendaScript >> /home/a/b/cronlogs/checkAgenda.log
```

Script:

```
cd /home/a/b/checkAgenda

java -jar checkAgenda.jar
sleep 20
java -jar checkAgenda.jar 
sleep 20
java -jar checkAgenda.jar
```

Comment: what does 1-6 represent?

Comment: @Phantom007 1-6 represents Monday to Saturday, where "-" is a range and "0" is Sunday. Here is a good link that explains very well all the fields and where you can test it: "https://crontab.guru/#*_\*_\*_\*_1-6"

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar task to do and use the following approach :

```
nohup watch -n30 "kill -3 NODE_PID" &
```

I needed to have a periodic kill -3 (to get the stack trace of a program) every 30 seconds for several hours.

```
nohup ... &
```

This is here to be sure that I don't lose the execution of watch if I loose the shell (network issue, windows crash etc...)

Answer (score -1):

Run in a shell loop, example:

```
#!/bin/sh    
counter=1
while true ; do
 echo $counter
 counter=$((counter+1))
 if [[ "$counter" -eq 60 ]]; then
  counter=0
 fi
 wget -q http://localhost/tool/heartbeat/ -O - > /dev/null 2>&1 &
 sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Even assuming that `60` should be a `30`, you might want to move that `wget` *inside* the `if` statement, otherwise it's executed every second. In any case, I'm not sure how this is any better than just a single `sleep 30`. If you were monitoring the actual UNIX time rather than your counter, it would make a difference.

Comment: echo the counter print out, you can find out time delayed by EXCUTE COMMAND if NOT run wget in background.

Answer (score -1):

Through trial and error, I found the correct expression: */30 * * ? * * *
This translates to every 30 seconds.
Reference: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html
They have provided the expression for running every second: * * * ? * * *
*/x is used to run at every x units. I tried that on the minute's place and viola. I'm sure others have already found this out, but I wanted to share my Eureka moment! :D

Comment: This is for Quartz, not cron.

Comment: @Reeth works perfectly for quartz, thank you