# how execute an script from server every 30 seconds - apache

Tags: php, apache, execution

how can I execute a php script from server every 30 seconds?

I have a php script and I need to execute it every 30 seconds to retrieve some information from other sites by curl.

but I dont know to run a php page in background by apache every 30 seconds.

Comment: You can create a cron job or a windows task (depends on your OS) and run that PHP script via command line. Would that suit you?

Comment: configure the script in crontab . . . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Cron job script.
Get a 30 seconds interval , you could delay  by 30 seconds:

```
-*/5-22 * * * sleep 30;your_script.php
```

The above script will run 5am to 10 pm

Comment: Using a solution like this, is not straight forward as Cron does not split its self into sub-minutes.. So this answer seems the best viable solution, you might have to conduct further tests into the stability of a solution like this.

Comment: the main disadvantage of this script is if the current script complete the execution in 20 seconds then the next cycle will be 50 as the timer didnt count the execution time.

Comment: So the OP will have to either sleep the PHP script for a few moments, or find another way to compensate this

Comment: The another method is if the script load take more time then conditional script also inserted.This can be override by conditional calls.In this case use two scripts.

Answer (score 2):

A cron run every minute. You should think about if one minute is enaugh.

[Running a cron every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds)

When you want to execute your script more often you need a deamon which run your script in a specified time. But its more complicated as a cronjob.

http://kvz.io/blog/2009/01/09/create-daemons-in-php/