# Cron Scheduling format guidance

Tags: cron

I want to run a cron every `30` seconds between `00:00` and `11:55`, *every day*, *every month*, *any day of the month*.

Is the following correct?

```
0/30 * 0-11 **
```

Comment: FYI, the smallest cron interval is one minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run your script every 30 seconds using the following:

```
* 0-11 * * * (sleep 30; /path/to/executable)
```

So your crontab should looks like

```
* 0-11 * * * /path/to/executable
0-54 0-11 * * * (sleep 30; /path/to/executable)
```

Both command lines will be executed at the same time, but the second one will do a 30 seconds sleep before executing your command.

Answer (score 3):

The format is as follows:

```
+---------------- minute (0 - 59)
|  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
|  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
|  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
|  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
|  |  |  |  |
*  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

So if you want to run every **minute** between 00.00 and 11.55, every day, every month, any day of the month, you need to combine two different lines:

```
* 0-10 * * * command
0-55 11 * * * command
```

Note that to run every 30 seconds you can use the trick described in [Running a cron every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619441/1983854).

Comment: No, given your constraints you have to specify a different minute range for the hour 11, thus you need two strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to validate your `cron` statement with decoder

One of them you can find by the link: http://cronwtf.github.io/