# Running cron less then one minute- laravel

Tags: linux, laravel, chron

I wanna ask if is there any way to set cron in laravel less then one minute. right now execute script in while true loop is inconsiderable. I'm talking about LINUX system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds

Comment: @Amo it's not a duplicate, OP is asking how you would do it through Laravel's inbuilt cron system.

Comment: Laravel's scheduler delegates to a single cron job which at its lowest interval is 1 minute so getting that to run faster than every minute requires the underlying cron to also be set up at a smaller interval, hence the duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not execute cron jobs with less than one minute interval.
You can check alternate solutions on 
https://serverfault.com/questions/49082/can-i-run-a-cron-job-more-frequently-than-every-minute