# Easy way to refresh php function with js

Tags: javascript, php, function, settimeout, setinterval

I have a PHP function that checks for the occurence of a string. What I want is to have it checked continously at a certain interval(eg: 5 seconds). From what I've gathered, PHP would be lesst than optimal for this 'refresh' function so looking for a way to do it with JS.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the silly question!

Comment: Why you want to run that function every 5 seconds?

Comment: Because the source changes and I want to keep searching at a set interval.

Comment: So you need to run that function every time the sources changes.

Comment: The source is data from a website. I do not control when the data changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think PHP would be less than optimal, but either way, I don't know of an "Easy" way. Cron jobs would typically be perfect for what you need, but they do not run sub-minute (although I have seen [interesting workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds)).

Node has a lot of packages for "cron" like functionality, but these take the same parameters, so no sub-minute.

You could utilize a [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) callback to accomplish this easily, but it would require you to a) keep a web client open 24/7 and b) monitor the web client to ensure it never freezes, fails, shuts down, etc.

Comment: I found that sleep() would do the job. Thanks for putting me in the right direction.