# How can we verify if a crontab job is running?

Tags: bash, cron

Background:

> I'm using **Sass** for CSS compilation with Bootstrap 3.
>
> Created a **gulp task** to trigger the compilation. 'gulp style'
>
> Got tired of executing the **gulp style** task every time I make a change to the scss file.
>
> Found out about crontab. Created my cron-file.txt to execute a bash file every 30 secs. Answer Courtesy : [Running a cron every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds)

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c "/my/path/autogulp.sh; sleep 30 ; /my/path/autogulp.sh"
```

autogulp.sh Contents

```
cd ~
cd /my/path/
gulp style
```

I tried running the commands *manually* and they seem to be *working fine*. Had to change the R/W mode for the cron-file.txt and autogulp.sh.
But my objective isn't fulfilled yet. The **'gulp style' isn't working automatically every 30 secs**.

I tried routing the std and error output to a file but the contents of the file are always empty.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: It is a pity that the person who voted down didn't leave a comment. This one is too good for a first question here at SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be an environment problem. Cron jobs are run with an extremely limited set of environment variables and they won't read your bash_profile or any other startup files. Even PATH may not be set. To verify this, run

```
$ env -i HOME=$HOME /path/to/script
```

from your terminal's command line prompt. If this can't run ("command not found"), add

```
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)
```

at the start of your script, then try again. Set all variables needed by the script in the script itself.