# Laravel 5 Schedule Task Not Working

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to make scheduled task for every 5 seconds.

This is my code.

```
  */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();

        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\SoapController@show')->cron('0,5 * * * *');


    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
```

And I'm getting this error when I enter

> php artisan schedule:run

command.

> No scheduled commands are ready to run.

Edit:

I Updated my scheduler and command section. I created a command.

And when I use it like

> php artisan get:data

its working.

But when I try it with scheduler its just working for 1 time.

```
protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\GetData::class,
    ];


 $schedule->command('get:data')->cron('* * * * *');
```

Comment: You have called the method "schedule" to create the task before you tried to call schedule:run?

Comment: Cron doesn't work with seconds. Your current cron command is saying run at 0 minutes past the hour and 5 minutes past the hour. Can you tell us why you need it to happen that regularly?

Comment: @RossWilson I need the get a data from a webservice in every 5 seconds. So I'm trying to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds

Comment: `0,5 * * * *` will execute at X:00 and X:05.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a scheduled task to run every *n* seconds. The system relies on a crontab task and these can only scheduled to the minute and no smaller unit. This is why it's not possible to define a scheduled task to run every *n* seconds, even with the `cron` method (since seconds aren't supported by cron).