# How to open a php file every half minute?

Tags: php, fopen

I want to write a file that does something every half minute, day and night, even after closing the browser. I use Windows7.
I have already tried this to open a file called "HaalG3.php" every half minute.

```
<?php 
    $sec="30"; 
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
    ignore_user_abort(true); 
    set_time_limit(0); 
    $file = fopen("HaalG3.php","r"); 
    header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page"); 
?>
```

This works fine as long as the calling file is open. HaalG3.php is opened every half minute.
But when I close the calling file nothing happens.
I have also added code from someone of Stack Overflow:

```
<?php 
    $sec="30"; 
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
    ignore_user_abort(true); 
    set_time_limit(0); 
    while (!file_exists('stop.txt')) {
        $file = fopen("HaalG3.php","r");  
        sleep(5);
    } 
    header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page"); 
?>
```

But when I use a while-loop I only see "Waiting for localhost" on the tab of Internet Explorer and nothing else happens.

Any help?

Comment: You can refresh your page with ajax. But i recommend to make the refresh as low as possible, because its server sided. Do you know who to to this?

Comment: Search google for `cron`

Comment: why don't you use a cronjob to run every 1 minute and run your code in a loop that lasts 30 seconds? In this case you wouldn't need browser at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a cron every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds)

Comment: @Oras That would cause the code to run every 1.5 minutes instead of every .5 minutes.

Comment: you can do this by cron job