# Python - Run code every 5 second block using UTC time

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to run a set of code that starts exactly in 5 second blocks from UTC time, starting at an even minute.

For example it would execute each sample at exactly:

```
11:20:45
11:20:50
11:20:55
11:21:00
11:21:05
11:21:10
```

I want that to happen regardless of execution time of the code block, if running the code is instant or 3 seconds I still want to execute at the 5 second UTC time intervals.

Not exactly sure how to do this, though I think that `datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp() - (datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp() % 5.0) + 5` gets me the next upcoming start time?

Comment: You execute the function in a different thread. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds

Comment: Just use `cron`...

Comment: Cron has a minimum interval of a minute.

Comment: @KlausD. But you could put 11 jobs with a sleep in increments of 5 :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619441/2308683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's [scheduler](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sched.html) module:

```
from datetime import datetime
import sched, time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def execute_something(start_time):
    print("starting at: %f" % time.time())
    time.sleep(3)  # simulate a task taking 3 seconds
    print("Done at: %f" % time.time())
    # Schedule next iteration
    next_start_time = start_time + 5
    s.enterabs(next_start_time, 1, execute_something, argument=(next_start_time,))

next_start_time = round(time.time() + 5, -1)  # align to next to 10sec
s.enterabs(next_start_time, 1, execute_something, argument=(next_start_time,))
print("Starting scheduler at: %f" % time.time())
s.run()


# Starting scheduler at: 1522031714.523436

# starting at: 1522031720.005633
# Done at: 1522031723.008825

# starting at: 1522031725.002102
# Done at: 1522031728.005263

# starting at: 1522031730.002157
# Done at: 1522031733.005365

# starting at: 1522031735.002160
# Done at: 1522031738.005370
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/time.html#time.sleep) to wait until the desired time. Note that this is approximate; especially when the system is under high load, your process might not be waken in time. You can [increase process priority](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.nice) to increase your chance.

To avoid blocking the waiting thread, run the task in a separate thread, either by constructing a new thread for every task or using a (faster) [thread pool](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor), like this:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

def do_something():  # Replace this with your real code
    # This code outputs the time and then simulates work between 0 and 10 seconds
    import datetime
    import random
    print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    time.sleep(10 * random.random())

pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
while True:
    now = time.time()
    time.sleep(5 - now % 5)
    pool.submit(do_something)
```