# How to setup my crontab in order to execute process_tasks in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, cron

I decided to use a library for my Django project called django-background-tasks (link to the documentation: https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I want to deploy my Django application to a Linux server (Ubuntu 19.0.4). How should I write the crontab in order to call the command "process_tasks" every five seconds?

Here [Running a cron every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds) is a workaround to achieve the seconds part, but since I am new to this part of the job (deploying and automation of process), how should I create my crontab file in order to achieve my desired purpose?

I'll be using process_tasks for a lot of different functionalities like: do some analysis at night and send results in the morning, expire some codes, etc. So basically I'll need to be running it almost constantly.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion, if you need something more I would be happy to provide it to you.

Comment: Cron only allows for a minimum of one minute. You can configure a [`systemd` timer](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/systemd.timer.5.html) with an `OnCalendar=*:0/5` directive as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know `cron` only allows for a minimum of one minute but you want to run it *every 5 seconds*.

how about writing a **shell script (running as a service via [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org)) that runs your task in an infinite loop**. This script will sleeps after every run for 5 seconds.

> The only difference between this `service` and a `cron` is:
>   A `cron` will fork a process every time it runs, a process runs your job and periodically check if the job is finished in order to clean it up, and this script (as service) will not work like cron but it'll do the job I believe.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    # your code here, 
    # call your python file which initializes 
    # django variables (or whatever you want) and do the needful.
    sleep 5;
done
```

You can configure a file `process_django_tasks.sh`(this file contains above code) with [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/) as a service so it runs on boot time and you have a control to `start` and `stop` with quick commands.

To test quickly you can easily run `sh process_django_tasks.sh`

If you could tell us why exactly you want your script to run every 5 seconds. Maybe we all suggest a better way than running a script every 5 sec.

Comment: I'll be using process_tasks for a lot of different functionalities like: do some analysis at night and send results in the morning, expire some codes, send emails after some views are executed so the users don't not have to wait till the email has been sent to receive a response, etc. So basically I'll need to be running it almost constantly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Supervisor (http://supervisord.org) to run `python manage.py process_tasks`, which will then monitor for the tasks you scheduled in your code and run them based on their repeat syntax:

To run your task every 5 seconds:

`function_to_call(var, repeat=5, repeat_until=None)`

I'd also recommend Supervisor to run your entire Django project.

> Looking at the documentation the `process_tasks` command by default runs every 5 seconds checking for new tasks to run. Not sure if you just wanted to check every 5 seconds or actually run a specific task every 5 seconds.

Comment: Hi, I am using process_tasks as a way of running scheduled calls to function inside my project, so is not like I want to run things every 5 secs, but that I'll need to do that in order to check constantly if there is a new process that I want to execute later on.

Comment: Ok, so you will want to start `process_tasks` as a continuous process and by default it will automatically check every 5 seconds if there is a task that it needs to run.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing any details, this may be a completely inapplicable alternative. However, if there is a guarantee that there will be nothing to be done until (an) instance(s) of (a) particular model(s) is saved, and provided that this save doesn't happen far too frequently, then you might look at Django `post_save` signals instead. Whenever that save happens, either execute the task, or execute the task if it wasn't run already in the last five seconds.

Comment: I see, the thing is that I'll be using process_tasks for a lot of different functionalities like: do some analysis at night and send results in the morning, expire some codes, etc. So basically I'll need to be running it almost constantly.