# How to put seconds in the Cron schedule with expressions in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, laravel-scheduler

I used cron expressions  `cron('*/3 * * * *')` and it means every 3 minute, but now I need in every 30 seconds. BUT I read that cron does not have anything for using seconds, also someone offered just repeat it 2 times with sleeping, but I guess it is just a crutch. And I tried to do something like that `cron(3 * * * * *)` but Laravel throw exception, that it is impossible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a cron every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Cron has a 60 sec granularity. Not a Laravel problem.

If you are running a recent Linux OS with SystemD, you can use the SystemD Timer unit to run your script at any granularity level you wish (theoretically down to nanoseconds), and - if you wish - much more flexible launching rules than Cron ever allowed. No sleep kludges required