# Is there a package for Linux that can run second-degree crontab

Tags: cron

The min time for a crond job is 1 minute, is there any package that has the same use as crontab and can set a second job

Comment: Seems none those kinds of tools exists, I will just modify crond for my own version, thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with SystemD on most modern Linux distributions. Please see this topic and the SystemD-specific answer in it:
[Running a cron every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds/9619441)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that way, sleep with a delay, but does there any package that can do the second job itself?

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no "real" way to run a job less than a minute with `cron` ...  I have used this work-around for years with no issues.  Say you wanted to run the cron every 30 secs.  You set 2 processes to run every minute ..  And set one to `sleep` for 30 secs.  IE

```
* * * * *  sh /path/to/script/shell.sh
* * * * * ( sleep 30; sh /path/to/script/shell.sh )
```

Effectively running the cron every 30 seconds.

Conversely if you wanted it to run every 20 seconds:

```
* * * * *  sh /path/to/script/shell.sh
* * * * * ( sleep 20; sh /path/to/script/shell.sh )
* * * * * ( sleep 40; sh /path/to/script/shell.sh )
```

**NOTE** this is a work-around!

Comment: Thanks, I knows that trick, but does there any package has the ability to do the second job itself

Comment: If that is your question, then the definitive answer is no.  :(

Comment: I check it in Google and GitHub, didn't found one, is that a great idea to just rewrite crond and publish a new package to do that job?