# Using crontab to execute script every minute and another every 24 hours

Tags: cron

I need a crontab syntax which should execute a specific PHP script `/var/www/html/a.php` every minute. The execution on every minute must start at 00:00. The other task which must execute a script at 00:00 `/var/www/html/reset.php` (once every 24 hours).

Answer (score 595, accepted):

every minute:

`* * * * * /path/to/php /var/www/html/a.php`

every 24hours (every midnight):

`0 0 * * * /path/to/php /var/www/html/reset.php`

See this reference for how crontab works: http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference, and this handy tool to build cron jobx: http://www.htmlbasix.com/crontab.shtml

Comment: Dear Jan! Great answer. How about running a cron every 30 seconds? Is it like this? * * * * */30 /path/to/php /var/www/html/a.php ?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't run cron jobs more frequently than every minute. You'll have to use something else for that.

Comment: Jan Hančič, you can do this. You just need to use a simple trick described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1034304/1580615

Comment: Is it normal practice to execute .php script each minute with cron? Can it reduce server productivity? Is there any other bad side effects?

Comment: @flaab for every 30 seconds you can try something like this: -

* * * * * curl --silent URL >/dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 30;  curl --silent URL >/dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 381):

This is the format of /etc/crontab:

```
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

I recommend copy & pasting that into the top of your crontab file so that you always have the reference handy. RedHat systems are setup that way by default.

To run something every minute:

```
* * * * * username /var/www/html/a.php
```

To run something at midnight of every day:

```
0 0 * * * username /var/www/html/reset.php
```

You can either include /usr/bin/php in the command to run, or you can make the php scripts directly executable:

```
chmod +x file.php
```

Start your php file with a shebang so that your shell knows which interpreter to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// your code here
```

Comment: That's the format of `/etc/crontab`, which is a *system* crontab file. A *user* crontab has a different format, which doesn't include the username field, since it runs as the user who submitted it. If you want to run a cron job as a non-root user, you should use the `crontab` command to submit it (and not worry about where the crontab is stored). Don't mess around with `/etc/crontab` unless you really need to.