# Can we set datetime to post new status to Twitter timeline from website?

Tags: php, twitter

Does anyone have experience with the Twitter API? I'm developing my site that can tweet status to twitter timeline from my site. Since now, a new status will post to twitter timeline after clicked on button Tweet.

However, I want to set datetime to post status to Twitter timeline. For example, I set datetime to post at 9AM and I click button at 8AM; so at 9AM, new status will be post in twitter timeline. Is that possible?

**My code**

This code will post new status when click on button Tweet:

```
<?php

session_start();
$message = "I want to set datetime to tweet new status";
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$parameters = array('status' => $message);
$status = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that references future postings in the [Twitter API documentation,](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update) so I'd imagine it is not possible.

I think the best way to handle this would be to store the tweet and the posting time in a database, and then have a PHP script run automatically and submit the Tweets at the correct time.

You can accomplish this by writing a script that contains the logic and then, if you're on a *nix server, using [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to execute the script at periodic intervals. Some additional information about using cron and PHP [can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/cron-crontab-execute-a-script-every-minute-and-another-one-every-24-hours/5398047#5398047)

Hope this helps!

**Note:** I'm not familiar with the Twitter API at all, so I'm not sure how it would work with authentication and scheduling tweets in the future. I imagine that if the user provides permission, you can post the tweet as described above, but it's just a SWAG.

Comment: Thank for your answer! I think we can scheduling tweets, i just found out this website: [Click Here](http://laterbro.com/)

Comment: I'm not sure if the scheduling is done through the API, though. The posting obviously is, but not sure about the scheduling.