# Automatic Schedule Scrapy Crawler With Amazon Web Services

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scrapy, scrapyd

I have a crawler/spider using Python's Scrapy, and I want to schedule a daily crawl with it using Amazon Web Services.

What I would like to do, is that every day, let's say 01:00 UTC. I want a ec2 instance to be created and launch the Scrapy spider and run the crawl, and when it's done I want the ec2 instance to be terminated.

I don't want the ec2 instance to be left up and running and add additional costs/fees because in the future I will add more spiders and it can result in a dozen of passive instances that do nothing 20h per day.

I found a couple of posts talking about using Scrapy with ec2:

- http://seminar.io/2013/03/26/running-scrapy-on-amazon-ec2/
- http://bgrva.github.io/blog/2014/04/13/deploy-crawler-to-ec2-with-scrapyd/
- http://www.dataisbeautiful.io/installing-scrapy-and-scrapyd-on-amazon-ec2/

But all of them seem to require you to launch that script from your local computer every time you want to schedule a crawl. It does not seem to be done automatically. I want my script to run 365 days a year, for 10+ years time, and I don't want to do it every night before I go to bed.

Can someone describe how this is done using Amazon Web Services?

Answer (score 3):

I think using [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours) or [python-scheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) along with the scrapyd will do the trick