# How can I call SELECT statements and print results on my webpage every 5 minutes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a webpage on which I want to present the results from the select query. Basically the query is simple:

```
SELECT text, timedate, duration from table;
```

and there is some mock data in my database - each text has assigned timedate which says when the text should appear on the screen and duration that says how long the text should appear for the user.
I want to construct either a php or jquery/javascript part that will make the select call to the database and return the table of results (that contains every text objects for the next 5 minutes) and displays it on the webpage. After that it should make a select query again and show data again - is that even possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux server than Use **Cron job** to execute the query file in every 5 minues and show print web page.

for more

refer this 
[Using crontab to execute script every minute and another every 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours)