# How do I schedule a cronjob?

Tags: php, cron

I've looked around online but can't find and simple explanations of how cronjobs function, and more specifically, where you command them to execute at a certain time.

I have found scripts like this:

```
0 1 * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/your_username/public_html/script.php
```

But it doesn't explain where I put this. Do I save it in another PHP file, or somewhere else?

I have found a Cronjob section in my cPanel, but I'd rather code it myself.

Thanks

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create cron job using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using crontab to execute script every minute and another every 24 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours)

Answer (score 1):

depending on your OS of your linux based server you would need to do this

first, ssh into your server.

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

this will likely give you a menu of options like this:

> Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
>
> 1. /bin/ed
> 2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
> 3. /usr/bin/vim.basic
> 4. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

choose which ever you are familiar with.

then input the line as you have specified.