# How can one input depend upon another input?

Tags: logstash

I have an `input` that requires information from another `input`. Specifically, the first input gets a security token from Zabbix, and the 2nd uses that token to make web requests.

What mechanism can I use to feed the 2nd `input` from the first?

Comment: I think it's not possible. You'll either have to do it in one exec command or perhaps retrieve the token before launching Logstash and using [an environment Variable](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html)(but that might not be possible, depending on your situation).

Comment: @baudsp Yes, I gave up on it yesterday - I'm tired of fighting the tool.. Thanks again.

Comment: There might be a way. See if this answer could work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436376/logstash-http-poller-first-url-requests-response-should-be-input-to-second-url/37438666#37438666