# logstash configuration: set filters for different purposes

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Is it possible to configure the same logstash.conf for different purposes?
For example:

- application log
- stacktrace of errors

I have a Spring Boot application and I use logstash-logback-encoder plugin

Comment: Almost certainly, but you'd have to stare at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html and figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [logstash http\_poller first URL request's response should be input to second URL's request param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436376/logstash-http-poller-first-url-requests-response-should-be-input-to-second-url)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but each index needs some kind of identification like for example type or tag. I prefer using tags because you might encounter a problem when your data has field called 'type'. Take a look at the example config file below for two indexes:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/log/app_log.log"
    tags => ["app_log"]
  }

  file {
    path => "/log/stacktrace.log"
    type => ["stacktrace"]
  }
}

filter {
  if "app_log" in [tags] {
  #Some fitlering for app_log  
  }
  if "stacktrace" in [tags] {
  #Some fitlering for stacktrace
  }

}

output {
   if "app_log" in [tags] {
      elasticsearch {
         index => "app_log-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
         hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      }
   }
   if "stacktrace" in [tags] {
       elasticsearch {
         index => "stacktrace-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
         hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
       }
   }
}
```

You can also add as many jdbc inputs as you want. You don't have to worry about a break time between different inputs because logstash runs every input in parallel.

Comment: can it also be done for tcp input? I thought about setting up two different ports and using two logstash appenders in the logback.xml

Comment: @AlessioFrabotta I never tried with tcp input but I thinkit it should work. You can always make 2 pipelines but with just a few inputs it's unnecessary complication.