# Data from ElasticSearch as input to http_poller

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, elk

I am trying to do the following:
Take some data (lets say a single floating point value) from kafka and add them to the body of an http call to some Rest API, through a Logstash pipeline. Is that really possible? I was trying to do this with a query to elasticsearch, with no luck. Find my Logstash pipeline below:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   kafka {
       bootstrap_servers => 'kafka:9094'
       topics => ["..."]
       client_id => "..."
       group_id => "..."
       codec => json {}
        }
  }
}

filter {
   http {
     verb => "POST"
     url => "http://some url"
     body_format => "json"
     body => {
       "instances" => "%{instances}"
     }
}

output{
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "elasticsearch:9200" ]
    index => "demo_results"
  }
}
```

In other words, I do not know how to send the data from elastic to the http_poller call!

Thanks a lot,

George.

Comment: All inputs are independent from each other so they do not communicate with each other and share noting. But maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37438666/4604579) can help

Comment: @Val, I can see your answer there, but to be honest I would like a more "elegant" solution using only Logstash. If I opt to go with scripts I could write an app which executes the http call and forwards results to elastic. Anyhow, is there any way I could add http_poller in some other part of the logstash where I could have access to the data returned from query? And how can I request a query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to leverage the [scheduling capabilities](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html#_scheduling) of the `elasticsearch` input so that it executes at regular time intervals to fetch whatever you need.

Then, when you get the data you wanted, you can use the [`http` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-http.html) to call your remote API using the data you fetched from Elasticsearch.

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["...:9200"]
    index => ["demo_data"]
    query => '{ "query": { "match": { "instances": 20 } } }'
    size => 1
    schedule => { cron => "* * * * * UTC"}
  }  
}
filter {
   http {
     verb => "POST"
     url => "http://some url"
     body_format => "json"
     body => {
       "instances" => "%{instances}"
     }
   }
}
output{
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "elasticsearch:9200" ]
    index => "demo_results"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the query right? My data are saved like this: {"instances": [[20.0]]}

Comment: If you data contains `instances` and you query for `statuscode`, nothing will match... maybe give some more insights into what you want to query exactly and how your data looks like in reality

Comment: My data are really like this: {"instances": [[20.0]]} and I want to get the floating point value (20.0) and transmit it to the http post call in the same exact way. So I want to send this message through http for the above data: body => '{"instances": [[20.0]]}' Is it possible to query for the whole instances message and send it to the http body?

Comment: I don't understand what statuscode is and what it does in your query then... Can you show a sample document you want to fetch?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I did not mention that I do not know how to query and this was only a dummy query for me to fill it later... I have {"instances": [[20.0]]} in  my elasticsearch, which I want to fetch and transmit later through the http call...

Comment: Ok, no worries. I've updated my answer, please try and let me know how it works. We might have to format the body differently, but let's go step by step

Comment: One last thing :), the floating point value in instances needs to be variable e.g. it can be 20.0 or 1.2 or 29.9 etc. How can I parse this?

Comment: The only way to pass "input" data to Logstash is by using [environment variables](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html), but if the value changes, Logstash needs to be restarted, defeating the purpose of scheduling... You might be better off configuring the cron in your shell, setting an environment variable for your floating point value and starting Logstash, which will run once and stop when done. If you tell how that floating point value is created or where it comes from, how and when it changes, there might be another way

Comment: Instead of using Elasticsearch as input, I did it through kafka, which is probably the same for my cause. Now my problem is, that I want to pass the input form kafka to the filter http post and get the response to output, is that possible? I will update the initial code.