# Update database table particular column of specific row automatically

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to make some real time updates on database without user interactions. I have columns as below

- ID
- Flight_Departure_Time
- Flight_Arrival_Time
- Status

User previously updates database as they can update Flight_Departure_Time & Flight_Arrival_Time . Now If arrival_time matches with current time it should automatically update status = Arrived at destination

How can I achieve this using mySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a cron Job or scheduled task to update the table in every 1 or 5 or 10 or 15 minute interval of time.

note that the latest update will get only after the given minutes.

[Using crontab to execute script every minute and another every 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours)