# How active a function with time interval PHP | Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

There's a way to call a function every minute? i have an API call from my codeigniter controller with cURL, can php call that function every min?

Comment: I wouldn't do that within PHP, because you're keeping the parser running waiting around just to run your function every minute. Have you considered using cron for this task?

Comment: Well i just need to recall an API every minute, how could i do that? _i had a headache using ajax (post) with codeigniter_

Comment: I'm assuming you need to recall an API to update your database every minute, or so some action every minute within that function. Create a file called `every_minute.php`, move the function/code you need to run every minute, and edit your cron file to include `* * * * * php /path/to/file/every_minute.php`. Would this be a viable solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using crontab to execute script every minute and another every 24 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours)

Answer (score 0):

in your hosting account you can create a CRONJOB and call it every 1 minute