# How to create crontab to run every one minute using linux command?

Tags: cron

---

I have the perl file named as perl.pl. I want this file  to run and output the contents  in new file using crontabs?

I dont know the steps how to perform it?Can anyone explain me with screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to open crontab by using:

```
crontab -e
```

This will open crontab in a text editor (usually this is vi or vim). Once inside the editor you will want to add:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/perl <PATH_TO_DIR>/perl.pl
```

This will run perl.pl once every minute. The five asterisks mean that the script will run every minute, every hour, every day of month, every month and every day of the week.

For more information on how crontab works read over some of the examples on [this page](https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a search before asking a question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398044/225905. TL;DR using all * for hour, month, day, and year will give you crontab once a minute. For example:

```
* * * * * /path/to/php /var/www/html/a.php
```

Once a minute is quite frequent for cron, and cron won't repeat any faster than that. It may be better to have your perl script run in the background and repeat its calculation once a minute.