# Why isn't my cron job Not running my PHP script?

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron, unlink

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 OS and LAMPP inside it. I want to schedule a cron job to run every minute, and execute a PHP script. So this is what I did:

Opened terminal and entered `crontab -e`

It opened the CronTab file in VIM and I pressed ESC to enter the INSERT mode and then wrote the following command:

```
* * * * * /opt/lampp/htdocs/Tests/16RunAPHPScriptInCronTab/index.php
```

Then I pressed `:wq` to Save and Exit. Got `installing new crontab` notification in terminal.

Now my actual script should check a directory in LAMPP local server for the presence of a `.pdf` or `.docx` file and if it does, then it should do some further work, but since to start with that, I needed to check if the cron job is *actually* running every minute. So what I did is that made my script do this:

If a file with the extension `.pdf` pr `docx` exists in the directory, it deletes them. **That way I will know if the cron job has run.**

**But this does not seem to work. A `.pdf` file is very much there and it is not getting deleted. So how would I know if my cron job is running correctly?**

The sources of my learning to do this are [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours) and [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/).

```
<?php

$pdfFileName = 'dumps/*.pdf';

$docxFileName = 'dumps/*.docx';

if ( (count(glob($pdfFileName)) > 0)   ||   (count(glob($docxFileName)) > 0) ) {

    /***********************************************/
    /*************** if the file exists ************/
    /***********************************************/

    if (file_exists($pdfFileName)) {
        unlink($pdfFileName);
    }

    if (file_exists($docxFileName)) {
        unlink($docxFileName);
    }

} else {
    echo "File does not exist.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *crontab* entry:

> `* * * * * /opt/lampp/htdocs/Tests/16RunAPHPScriptInCronTab/index.php`

means that `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Tests/16RunAPHPScriptInCronTab/index.php` *command* is run every minute just as if you typed this string in terminal and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The command will fail, if at least one of the following is true:

- the current user has no execution permissions for the file/directory;
- the file is not a shell script, and the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is not specified

So you should make sure that the script is executable for the user that runs the *crontab*, and the file contains shebang, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Alternatively, run the script by explicitly invoking the `php` executable:

```
* * * * * php /opt/lampp/htdocs/Tests/16RunAPHPScriptInCronTab/index.php
```

If `php` is not available in `PATH`, either specify the full path to `php`, or add the appropriate path to the `PATH` environment variable. The most popular implementations allow to set `PATH` via *crontab*, e.g.:

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

(before the entries with the commands.)

Comment: Hey can I just echo out something in the _test_ PHP script, just to check if a cron job is executing a PHP script correctly? Where will it be echoed? In the browser? How? What is the simplest way which can tell me if my cron job is executing my php script correctly?

Comment: @Sie, `echo` prints text to the standard output descriptor. So the text will appear at the end point connected to the standard output. You can redirect it to a file as `php script.php > /tmp/output`

Comment: OK I installed **`* * * * * php /opt/lampp/htdocs/Tests/16RunAPHPScriptInCronTab/index.php > /opt/lampp/htdocs/Tests/16RunAPHPScriptInCronTab/output.txt`** cron job, and a file named `output.txt` IS being created at the path specified every minute but when I open it is EMPTY. Whereas the PHP script I am trying to run now is `<?php echo "Hello, world!";   ?> `.

Comment: So shouldn't `Hello, world!` be printed to `output.txt`?

Comment: @Sie, It should, if you do not overwrite the file in another command. Try this. 1. create `/tmp/test.php` with the following code: `<?php echo 'hello';`. 2. Put `* * * * * php /tmp/test.php > /tmp/test.out` into _crontab_. 3. Wait for 60 seconds. 4. `cat /tmp/test.out`.

Comment: `test.out` IS created. When I manually open it with GEdit, it appears EMPTY. When I execute `cat /tmp/test.out`, nothing happens.

Comment: @Sie, looks like `php` is not available in `PATH`. Replace `php` with the output of `which php`, e.g. `/usr/bin/php`. Also redirect standard error to some file: `/usr/bin/php /tmp/test.php >/tmp/out 2>/tmp/error`

Comment: `which php` does not produce any output. Nothing happens when I execute `which php`.

Comment: @Sie, okay, find out the path to the `php` executable, and use that path

Comment: Is _`php` executable_ the file which has `Type: Link to executable (application/x-executable)` in its properties? It's located at `/opt/lampp/bin/php`.

Comment: @Sie, yes, I mean the PHP CLI binary. On Ubuntu you can install `php7.0-cli`, or `php5-cli` packages from the main repository

Comment: At `/opt/lampp/bin/` directory, there is a file named `php` and a file named `php-7.0.9`. When I right-click them and choose `Properties` from menu, it says `Type: Link to executable (application/x-executable)` and `Type: executable (application/x-executable)`. So which one should I use? I think the second one?

Comment: @Sie, `php` is likely a symbolic link to `php-7.0.9`, so choose the former.

Answer (score 1):

```
* * * * * php /opt/lampp/htdocs/Tests/16RunAPHPScriptInCronTab/index.php
```

Comment: Thank you. By **`php`**, do you mean the path **`/opt/lampp/bin/php`** ?

Comment: usually just php is ok, for it has been write to the path variable.

Comment: Hey can I just echo out something in the test PHP script, just to check if a cron job is executing a PHP script correctly? Where will it be echoed? In the browser? How? What is the simplest way which can tell me if my cron job is executing my php script correctly?

Comment: it's output to the stdout. not the browser.

Comment: I installed **`* * * * * php /opt/lampp/htdocs/Tests/16RunAPHPScriptInCronTab/index.php`** crobjob and the PHP script only contains **`echo 'Hello World';`** , but I waited and waited but nothing output in the terminal. Here are contents of the terminal: 
`jes@ubuntu:~$ crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
jes@ubuntu:~$ `

Comment: here the stdout is the process space stdout. not the terminal.

Comment: you may write the output to a file, or use pipe stream.