# Run bash script on schedule

Tags: bash, time, backup

I have some problem with bash script. I need to add some content to it. My script need to run at a certain time but I don't know how to do that. It should work like this:
I have a variable then I assign a time like 3200s. When I run the program, then the script will create backups every 3200s but only if some files changed. What am I doing wrong?

```
!/bin/bash

SOURCE="/var/www/my_web/load/"
BACKUP="/home/your_user/load/"
LBACKUP="/home/your_user/load/latest-full/"

DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%T)

DESTINATION="$BACKUP"/"$DATE"-diff/

rsync -av --compare-dest="$LBACKUP" "$SOURCE" "$DESTINATION"

cd "$DESTINATION"
find . -depth -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: Check the `cron` and `at` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i have added that feature to your script:

usage:

```
./yourscript.sh 3200
```

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# make sure you gave a number of seconds:
[ 0$1 -gt 0 ] || exit

while true; do
    SOURCE="/var/www/my_web/load/"
    BACKUP="/home/your_user/load/"
    LBACKUP="/home/your_user/load/latest-full/"

    DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%T)

    DESTINATION="$BACKUP"/"$DATE"-diff/

    rsync -av --compare-dest="$LBACKUP" "$SOURCE" "$DESTINATION"

    cd "$DESTINATION"
    find . -depth -type d -empty -delete

    sleep $1
done
```

if you get an error like `bash: ./yourscript.sh: Permission denied`, then you need to do this once: `chmod +x yourscript.sh` to make the script executable.

to continue running in background even after you leave the terminal window:

```
nohup ./yourscript.sh 3200 &
```

to run in background on schedule even after restart:

use `cron`, e.g., [Using crontab to execute script every minute and another every 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours)