# How to load csv data into Google Cloud SQL(PostgreSQL table) automatically from compute engine

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want to load csv into Cloud SQL (Postgres)  automatically from compute engine. i am able to connect cloud sql (postgres) from compute engine. But i want load csv  generated from XML in compute engine  into Cloud SQL (Postgres) .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table)

Comment: No,it does n't. fyi, i am loading csv from google compute engine into google cloud SQL (PostgreSQL)

Comment: Edit your question to clearly state what you are asking. Are you looking for a tool (off-topic for Stack Overflow), which programming language (what have you tried, post your code), someone to write code for you (someone might be generous). There are over 100 questions about CSV and PostreSQL on Stack Overflow. None of them help you?

Answer (score 0):

Given that every GCE instance has `gcloud` SDK installed by default, you can follow [this command instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/import/csv) and [write your own scipt](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud) to perform the import operation.

Then you can [set a schedule for your bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952209/run-bash-script-on-schedule) operation to run on x interval of time