# How to fetch updated JSON data continuously using python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, cron

While working with json in python, I've written this small script to fetch the current price of BTC. This works fine when I run the script in Ubuntu terminal.

What I want is to update the variable `current_price` for every minute so that I can use this variable to display a desktop notification for current price.

I was looking for `cron` to schedule the task but It'll not work because I want to run the script after each minute, not at a specific time.

what is the best practice to achieve this?

```
import urllib, json

url = "https://koinex.in/api/ticker"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

current_price = data["prices"]["BTC"]

print current_price
```

Comment: You can set up `cron` to run every minute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the script [**every minute you can use cron job**](https://crontab.guru/every-1-minute):

**EX:**

```
* * * * * python /PATH_TO_SCRIPT/script.py
```

Comment: I've added the job in cron tab. 

* * * * * python ~/price.py

How do I know if the job is working? Will a new terminal popup each minute with the value of current_price ?

Comment: You add a logging function inside the script to check it

Comment: Working fine! Thanks a ton Rakesh