# Run JavaScript app on server even if webpage is closed

Tags: javascript, server, automation

I did a little robot which get every 30 seconds a place temperature in JavaScript. 
This robot sends the results via slack every 5 minutes. In order to keep the robot running, I need to keep the page open on my navigator.

I thought If I put my JS app on a little webhost and make it run even if the page is closed could solve my problem, but no. How can I make it running on my webhost even if the page is closed?

Maybe is it possible if I change language, PHP? Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours

Comment: PHP would work, or nodejs if you want to stick to JavaScript. You'll need to make it a service or use chron to execute it how ever often you want it run.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I just would like to be sure for PHP, before.

Comment: @NickSlash How can I loop every 30 seconds without any javascript, should I use sleep function ?