# How to use rsync to synchronise a folder that is constantly updating with images/video files on a server

Tags: server, digital-ocean, rsync

I have used rsync to move files across previously however I want to know the best solution for moving across files from a directory that has new files added to it regularly and have this sync on the other remote server what is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cron` to update your folder constantly, for example like in this case: [Using crontab to execute script every minute and another every 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours)