# How to run my script that opens a web browser script from server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, centos, whatsapp

I'm automating a few things where I work regarding communication using WhatsApp. I have implemented a few scripts using Python ([pywhatkit](https://pypi.org/project/pywhatkit/) and [MySQLdb](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html)) that acess my work's database and sends out a few text messages. The thing is, we currently have a local CentOS server up and running and I don't know how to make my script run on that. Like, I was told that the server had no graphical interface, and my script basically opens Firefox and sends texts every once in a while.

How can I make this work from this server? Is there another alternative? This will be used to send a couple of texts every day, so It won't be CPU intensive. Best use scenario would be to run this script every day at a scheduled time, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours) to run script once per day.

Also you can open headless Firefox on CentOS server. Here [good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python) how to do it.