# Cronjob not running to completion

Tags: php, linux, cron, turnkeylinux.org

I am currently experiencing a strange problem, I have created a large script which doesn't seem to run to completion every time.

To elaborate, the script executes a lot of queries to the database and API's to update dataon my website. It has been running for several weeks now, but before that and at the time of writing the script will stop running if it is started multiple times (2, usually) in a row.. sometimes.

So the problem is not very consistent, but it is a vital part of my website and I need it to run once every day at a specific time to keep everything running.

The script itself shouldn't be the problem. At first we had to fix a problem where it would receive a timeout. Timeouts are a big problem because the script can take up to an hour to finish.

What I've checked:

**- Are any cronjobs interfering with my cronjob?**
* Not as far as I can see. A lot of standard maintainence crons are running, but they shouldn't cause any problems? The other cronjobs we created ourselves are not running while the problematic cronjob is.

**- Do I have enough memory left?**
* Almost too much.

**- Does the script work as it should, could it be the cause of the problems you are having?**
* Could be, but I don't see how. I've checked the script manually a million times.

**- Did you turn on the logs?**
* I didn't, this might be a good idea but I don't know which log(s) to turn on. Also, we've had error-reporting problems in the past, so I'm afraid it's not going to catch anything if I turn it on.

**What I'm running:**
- Turnkey Linux

As a finisher, the script is hard to debug, it takes about an hour to finish and afaik it never stops at the same code.

tl;dr: How should I debug a cronjob that seems to crash randomly for a while and then stops crashing for long periods of time?

**Edit**
Thank you for the swift responses
@Basile Starynkevitch: We have tried that, but it doesn't throw any errors, it just stops. There is nothing in the script that could cause that.

I cant show you relevant parts of the script I think, it's much too large. But what it all comes down to is a lot of queries and data processing.

@fedorqui: cd /var/www/cronjobs/ && /usr/bin/php -q -f sc_distri_cronjob.php
It is in a public folder for testing purposes, but I don't think it has anything to do with my problem. Since the scripts runs succesfully for long periods of time, I guess the permissions are fine?

@Flosculus: We have a lock in place, this is what caught our attention. It runs "fine" once, then we run it again and it tells us the file is still locked even though it stopped running. The lock is released at the end and it contains no errors, nothing in the script could purposefully stop it from running.

Comment: Put `#!/bin/sh -vx` at start of script. Redirect its *stderr* and *stdout* outputs in the crontab entry. Also use `logger` inside to give messages at crucial points.

Comment: Basic questions: is your script running standalone? what is your crontab line? does the file have execute permissions for the user running it? can this user run crontab?

Comment: And show relevant parts of your script and the crontab entry line.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428631/php-preventing-collision-in-cron-file-lock-safe, it will at least help prevent multiple runnings.

Comment: log log and then add more logging, till you find the issue(s)

Comment: Try logging memory usage

Comment: I have updated my question to answer yours. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: I would update to `/usr/bin/php -q -f /var/www/cronjobs/sc_distri_cronjob.php` instead of using the `cd` part.

Comment: Why is that? Does that benefit me somehow?

Comment: Crontab does not have any environment variables and prefers full paths instead of relative ones.

Answer (score 1):

Since your script is very large it may run longer then your php.ini's max_execution_time.
Try the usage of [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) with a big enough amount of time.
Maybe you also track how long your script is running averagely and adjust the call.

Comment: As a test it's been set to 8 hours, the problem still persists.

Comment: Then your only chance in getting this solved is logging. @Basile Starynkevitch's approach is really good for this.

Comment: Alright, thank you, we probably found the answer but we'll have to wait untill monday.

Comment: cli (cron) scripts have NO time limit