# how to run the python program using cron scheduling

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I want a python webscraping program to be run everyday at a certain time. For that i am using this command in the cron in ubuntu

```
28 22 * * * root /home/ahmed/Desktop python hello.py
```

It just doesnt work. there must be something wrong with it. can anyone help me please?

Comment: Does it work when you manually issue `/home/ahmed/Desktop python hello.py` command? Probably you need something like `28 22 * * * root python /home/ahmed/Desktop hello.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `#!/usr/bin/python` (called shebang line) to the top of your Python script and then

```
28 22 * * * root /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py
```

You have to make your script executable like this (run this as a separate command):
`sudo chmod +x /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py`

From the [Shebang page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on Wikipedia:

> Under Unix-like operating systems, when a script with a shebang is run
>   as a program, the program loader parses the rest of the script's
>   initial line as an interpreter directive; the specified interpreter
>   program is run instead, passing to it as an argument the path that was
>   initially used when attempting to run the script.[8] For example, if a
>   script is named with the path "path/to/script", and it starts with the
>   following line:
>   #!/bin/sh then the program loader is instructed to run the program "/bin/sh" instead (usually this is the Bourne shell or a compatible
>   shell), passing "path/to/script" as the first argument.

If you don't want to change anything this will work as well:

`28 22 * * * root python /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py`

Comment: # is supposed to be a comment in the python script, isnt it?

Comment: `#` is a comment *in Python*, yes but [`#!` has special meaning to *the OS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). You'll also need to ensure that `/home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py` [has the executable bit set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).

Comment: I put the #!/usr/bin/python in the python script (which is recognized as a comment by the text editor) and then ran the command as u mentioned, but still it doesnt work

Comment: @user3415869 you also have to make your script executable: `sudo chmod +x /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py`

Comment: i did it but still doesnt show anything in my database :(

Comment: @user3415869 then the problem is in the script itself, and not the way you run it

Comment: Am i doing something correct? i intend to run a python script in the background automatically at a specific time. the program is connected to my local server's database and inserting values in that. i am checking whether the program is running or not by checking the database(that whether the values are being inserted or not)

Comment: no the script is correct. when i run it without cron it runs well

Comment: @user3415869 Okay, did you try to run it this way: `28 22 * * * root python /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py`?

Comment: yes . i used this command 02 23 * * * sudo chmod +x python /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py

Comment: @user3415869 note: crontab doesn't immediately run your script. Consult the manual (http://kb.iu.edu/data/afiz.html). Crontab **will** launch this script at 22:28 every day.

Comment: @user3415869 this is wrong. `02 23 * * * sudo python /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py` is correct

Comment: working now! Thanks! Can u guide me with a command which runs the script every second? and secondly, will this program run when my computer is turned off?

Comment: @user3415869 The program won't work if your computer is turned off. This is how to run the script every n seconds : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034243/how-to-get-a-unix-script-to-run-every-15-seconds

Comment: is there any way i can run the program every minute forever regardless of my computer is turned on or off?

Comment: @user3415869 there is no way to do it, I'm assured

Answer (score 2):

`/home/ahmed/Desktop` is (most probably!) not a valid command name.  You want

```
28 22 * * * root python hello.py
```

or possibly

```
28 22 * * * root python /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py
```

depending somewhat on why you put that folder name there.

The syntax of a regular user's `crontab` is different.  I can imagine no legitimate reason to run a scaping program as `root`.  To run it from your own `crontab` you should use

```
28 22 * * * python /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py
```

(again possibly without the path name, or with the path somewhere else in the command line).

Comment: perfect! thanks. will this program run if my computer turned off?

Comment: A `cron` job will not cause your computer to turn on by itself, no.  Cron is not running either when there is no power.

Comment: See however http://askubuntu.com/questions/8845/how-do-i-schedule-waking-up-from-hibernation

Comment: i intend to run this program forever for every minute whether my pc is turned off or on. is there any way to do it?

Comment: This is no longer programming related.  Post a new question to http://askubuntu.com/ or a similar forum.