# How to specify run timing for bash scripts?

Tags: php, bash

I was looking for a way to continuously run a PHP script every 15 seconds online, so that I may manage some accounts using an API. I was able to find a script that satisfies what I was looking for as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script runs every 15 seconds
#This script is ran in /etc/rc.local (startup)

while (sleep 15 && php test.php) &
do
    wait $!
done
```

This script works perfectly and runs every 15 seconds. However, now I want to modify the script such that it may

1. do what the script is already doing
2. run a second script, every 5 minutes

Is there a way to modify the current while loop so that I may achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: on point 2 ). You can use crontab to schedule bash scripts. Here are few examples on that. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/ did not understand point 1.

Comment: Edited point 1) for clarity. Thanks for the suggestion, just debating what method I should go with now.

Comment: I thought this link would further help to conclude: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119069/cron-vs-sleep-which-is-the-better-one-in-terms-of-efficient-cpu-memory-utiliz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are much better ways to do this because PHP requires and HTTP request to run that file.

1. Run a cron job to run this request every set interval (not recommended)
2. Use another program like python which can run a daemon to do this
3. Do the calculation every time the page is requested (recommended and almost always possible)

Comment: Could you detail a bit more about how the example script in the OP should not be used? Sorry, a little bit of a beginner. Could you also detail #3 a little more too?

Comment: In order to invoke the script you need to have a request going, PHP has a timeout (which causes the thread to close automatically), its not designed to do long running requests. There are few exceptions to this rule like long-polling. As for the third, an example would be like your outstanding notifications, every time you visit a page the website counts them on each request. Most websites do it this way as it is cheaper and doesn't require shell access. Also for notifications generated by other users, you simply generate the messages on their request.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to clarify, the PHP script isn't hosted anywhere and is only running on my local system. The script is intended to read data from a few API requests, and then do a specific action accordingly. Not sure if that changes anything. Thanks again.

Comment: Yep, no problem, in that case then I would just recommend not using PHP. Python would be a better alternative as it is designed way to better to run as standalone system than PHP. You can also run a python web server in that environment while polling that data.

Comment: Good information to know. Thanks a lot. I would strongly consider python if it didn't require me to learn the language first haha :). Would a cron job be a valid option in a local script situation? I would like to stick with PHP/bash as much as possible.

Comment: It is, but it is really a duct tape solution in my opinion, plus you will have a cache you will have to clear regularly of html files generated by PHP on every request (If you invoke it by HTTP, im not sure about command line). Look into PHP command line, it will come in useful for invoking php by bash.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have more than enough information now to choose a solution. I'll choose your answer as my solution, as you listed several options I may go with. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a loop

Runs forever until you terminate it, although yours also does.

Change sleep to whatever interval you want, i just set it to 1 for this example.

Set up if statements and use modulus to set the time frame for each one, also probably want to set count back to `0` in the highest timed `if` to stop it getting too large.

You can add as many as you want for as many times as you want :)

```
#!/bin/bash

while (true)
do
    sleep 1
    if (( count % 15 == 0 )) ;then
            php test.php
    fi
    if (( count % 300 == 0 )); then
            SecondScript
            count=0
    fi

     (( count = count +1 ))


done
```

Comment: I may go with this option depending what I learn about my other options. I am trying to find the best possible solution, but this looks like what I am looking for! Thanks :).

Comment: Definitely a good example of php command line implementation +1

Comment: @Jidder tried using this loop, but it's telling me that the counter is not found when running it. Can't seem to figure out where the bug is.

Comment: @Jidder It looks like the script isn't finding the counter:

`script.sh: 8: script.sh: count: not found
script.sh: 11: script.sh: count: not found
script.sh: 16: script.sh: count: not found
`

Comment: Is the script exactly the same as the one i posted ?

Comment: @Jidder Does the count variable have to be instantiated prior to the loop? I'm not too familiar with bash.

Comment: You could instantiate it before the loop, but it shouldnt matter as when a variable is called it is set to 0 as far as i know.

Comment: @Jidder That's what I assumed. I honestly don't know why the script isn't working in that case. Logic checks out.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do such kind of things is via "Cron Job".

> The software utility Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like
>   computer operating systems. People who set up and maintain software
>   environments use cron to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to
>   run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals.

source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Useful Source: [How to get a unix script to run every 15 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034243/how-to-get-a-unix-script-to-run-every-15-seconds)

Comment: I would recommend against it because then you have a false visitor polling the site in order to keep the script alive, PHP isn't designed to do this, see my answer for alternatives

Comment: I did consider using a CronJob for this type of thing, but I found the script above and it gave me results. Any reason why I should use CronJob over the above script? Thanks.