# setting time in seconds for cronjobs

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have to run 3 shell scripts at intervals of 15 seconds continuously and automatically when the system runs.

Is it possible to add a cronjob with the following interval?

```
0.25 * * * * sudo bash /home/ckoy-admin/HAS_system/execute/FS.sh
```

I am trying to use 0.25 minutes, but it does not work.

Comment: See: [How to get a unix script to run every 15 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1034243/3776858)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a unix script to run every 15 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034243/how-to-get-a-unix-script-to-run-every-15-seconds)

Comment: cron doesn't support sub-minute scheduling, trying to "trick" it is optional but I'm not sure it's wise. Use a tool that supports such a requirement , for example, Java's `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` [supports such scheduling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))