# How to automatically call a Firebase function every 15 seconds

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When required to call a Firebase Function every certain time, I've always used Google Cron tasks.

But now, I have to call a function every 15 seconds. The smallest interval that Google Cron allows is 1 minute (linux like).

What would be the best practice to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Given the latency on calls to Cloud Functions, are you sure it's a good fit for a use-case requiring that granularity?

Comment: Is your stack entirely serverless? If you have a box (e.g. on google compute engine) you could write a little script that is executed every 15 secs to make the http call. Dev. think about pricing of cloud functions https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing-summary/

Comment: what do you think about advice from @ArtjomZabelin? Take a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034243/how-to-get-a-unix-script-to-run-every-15-seconds
I think you will find this useful